# Deployment of PHP application to Google AppEngine failing with 403 error

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been trying to deploy my application to Google AppEngine recently and is failing with below errors -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/bin/appender.par/__main__.py", line 90, in <module>
  File "/bin/appender.par/__main__.py", line 81, in main
  File "/bin/appender.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_session_.py", line 301, in upload
  File "/bin/appender.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_session_.py", line 107, in _manifest_exists
  File "/bin/appender.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_http_.py", line 377, in Request
containerregistry.client.v2_2.docker_http_.V2DiagnosticException: response: {'status': '403', 'content-length': '292', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'Docker Registry', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'docker-distribution-api-version': 'registry/2.0', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Thu, 18 Jun 2020 04:28:15 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
```

I was able to deploy it successfully until 9th March this year. Let me know if any more information is required for helping me resolve this.

Here are the things that i have already verified:

- Cloud API is already enabled
- User i am trying from is owner of account

Comment: Try disabling and reenabling the Cloud Build API, this will make all the permission be re-created and override any permissions that were broken. Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: It turned out that my billing account for the concerned project was closed due to card expiry. I got it opened and able to deploy. Thanks @ralemos for suggesting to disable and re-enable cloud build API as i got notification to open billing account at the time of re-enabling.

Comment: Ok, good to know that the issue is fixed. I will add that to an official answer, please do remember to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities that could be generating this error:

- Billing is Disabled;
- Permissions are broken;

So in order to fix it I would recommend you to disable and reenable the Cloud Build API, this will make all the permission be re-created and override any permissions that were broken for your service accounts and also make sure that you have billing properly set for your project.

Both these actions should fix the issue you are facing.